# apt-get update doesn't work gives an error

Tags: apt, package-management, updates, dpkg

```
Errors were encountered while processing:
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libsdl2_2.0.3+z4~20140315-8621-1ppa1trusty1_i386.deb
 /var/cache/apt/archives/libsdl2-image_2.0.0+z1~20131109-434-1ppa1trusty2_i386.deb
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Seems since I installed `vdrift` the update manager isn't updating any more.
I tried to search for a fix and used

```
sudo apt-get -f install
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get upgrade
sudo dpkg --configure -a
sudo dpkg clean
```

also used synaptic  (finds 2 broken packets. but cannot fix them or remove them)

any idea ?

Comment: Could you please the first line of the output above to English? You can run a single terminal command with the language set to English by writing `LANG=C ` before it. Example: `LANG=C sudo apt-get update` - And you mistyped "at-get" instead of "apt-get" in your second code block.

Comment: changed that to english and the typo. but stil having the problem cannot update.

Comment: ok tried again with synaptic and eventually i was able to remove the 2 packages that gave me the problem. updater seems to work again.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following commands:

```
sudo apt-get check
sudo apt-get clean
```

The first one (*check*) might do nothing,
but the second one (*clean*) should delete all downloaded and cached packages including the two faulty packages above.

No worries, this does not affect the installed programs but does just empty the cache of apt-get. You will not notice it except that the next time you install something, apt-get might have to download a little bit more...

Answer (score 0):

Try to remove/purge the faulty packages:

```
sudo dpkg -P /var/cache/apt/archives/libsdl2_2.0.3+z4~20140315-8621-1ppa1trusty1_i386.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/libsdl2-image_2.0.0+z1~20131109-434-1ppa1trusty2_i386.deb
```

Then fix the broken dependencies so that if they were needed they'll be reinstalled:

```
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Then retry.